# No suitable constructor found for entity type HierarchyId

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I working in DotNet core 3.1 and need to use hierarchy structure and I have to use HierarchyId in my table and I use Code First. But when I try execute **add-migration** it returns this error:

> No suitable constructor found for entity type 'HierarchyId'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'value' in 'HierarchyId(SqlHierarchyId value)'.

This is my Entity class

```
public class MyHClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HierarchyId Level { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my context class that before adding MyHClass worlds find and add tables to the database correctly.

```
public class ArtiDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ArtiDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public new DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : BaseEntity
    {
        return base.Set<T>();
    }

    public DbSet<SampleEntity> SampleEntity { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MyHClass> MyHClasses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
}
```

this is my package that I am installed:

```
<PackageReference Include="EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.4">
```

for more information I put whole error here too :

```
PM> add-migration
cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: gh
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor found for entity type 'HierarchyId'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'value' in 'HierarchyId(SqlHierarchyId value)'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ConstructorBindingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
No suitable constructor found for entity type 'HierarchyId'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'value' in 'HierarchyId(SqlHierarchyId value)'.
```

Comment: I also search on the net and just one issue someone set here and no one answered! https://github.com/bricelam/EFCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId/issues/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add `x.UseHierarchyId()` to your `Startup.cs`

```
options.UseSqlServer(
    connectionString,
    x => x.UseHierarchyId());
```

BTW, `SqlHierarchyId` is not compatible with .NET Core unless you're using dotMorten's version `dotMorten.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`.
If that's really the case, then you have no reason using `EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId` at all.