# Error with HierarchyId datatype with Entity Framework Core 6 & .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am a beginner in programming. I created an ASP.NET Core 6 project using EF Core 6. When I try to reverse-engineer an existing SQL Server 2019 database using `Scaffold-DbContext`, all domain classes are created with properties `HierarchyId` like this :

```
public partial class Country
{
    public HierarchyId Id { get; set; } = null!;
    public HierarchyId Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public HierarchyId ParentId { get; set; } = null!;
    public HierarchyId hierarchyId { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

My dependencies:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.01;
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.01;
Microsft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlsServer.HierarchyId 3.00;
```

When trying to migrate property with type `HierarchyId`, I get this error:

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'HierarchyId'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'value' in 'HierarchyId(SqlHierarchyId value)'

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62565446/11186444) answer your question?

Comment: I sorry it may work with EF Core 3.1 or 5 but i use EF Core 6 so it doesn't work with

Comment: It looks like a bug to me, it would be better if you open an issue [here](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId). Also, `Country` got all properties of type `HierarchyId`, they have opened an [issue](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId/issues/86) about it, I suggest you follow it.

Comment: I am so sorry I can't understand is Issue #84 Solved or not or I need To update my Package :- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.HierarchyId